# Custom table naming/access convention for multisite: $table_prefix vs base_prefix or other?

Tags: plugins, multisite, customization, table

After WP3.8.1 upgraded, two plugins I made for my networks both stopped working.  Each runs on a separate multisite install.  I posted the error report on the Wordpress form: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/table_prefix-error-since-wp-381-upgrade?replies=1

For Multisite, is there a better way of accessing my custom table than using
 `$my_custom_table = $wpdb->$table_prefix.'my_custom_table';`?
I see here the use of base_prefix: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/multisite-table-prefix-wpdb-prefix-incorrect?replies=6

Would it be better to rename my custom table as
`wp_my_custom_table`, instead of
 
`my_custom_table`, and use 
`$my_custom_table = $wpdb->base_prefix('my_custom_table');`.

This outputs `wp_my_custom_table`.

Or are there advantages to leaving the table name as is, using `$table_prefix`, and waiting for the error report to be resolved?